# Adding ACE+TAO with numerous compile errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, corba, ace, tao

I am adding ACE TAO to my existing project, and I have compile errors after adding the projects. Most of the errors were "No such file or directory", and these errors can simply be fixed by changing the patch of the #include, but there are thousands of them, and I am thinking I must have done something wrong on my end.

For example, in ace/Assert.h, it has

```
#include ace/pre.h
#include ace/ACE_export.h
#include ace/config-all.h
```

but Assert.h is also in the ace directory. These type of errors are every where in the ACE TAO project, am I doing something wrong? or do I just need to fix the #include paths manually?

Comment: In your project settings you should have settings for additional include directories and additional library directories.  You will needs to set those to point that header and library locations respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It fixes my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "No such file or directory" you should add the file path:

1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
2. Select the Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General property page.
3. Modify the Additional Include Directories property.

[image]

Since you have other errors, I guess you may not have installed the Windows SDK for the corresponding operating system, you could install it in the visual studio installer.

[image]

If the program has other errors, please upload the relevant details.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers. It fixes the problem I was having